# awk returning empty output though the string is present

Tags: shell, awk, grep

I have the below command

```
$  bx cs clusters | grep "ibmc-s3-e2e-test"
   ibmc-s3-e2e-test              1dfcc223e4744ccd891e7ac952707c99    normal   31 minutes ago   2         Dallas     1.10.7_1520   
   Ambikas-MacBook-Pro-2:~ ambikanair$ bx cs clusters | awk "ibmc-s3-e2e-test"
   Ambikas-MacBook-Pro-2:~ ambikanair$
```

How does these two commands differ. `grep` gives me the required output but `awk` doesn't.

Comment: `awk "ibmc-s3-e2e-test"` should be `awk '/ibmc-s3-e2e-test/'`

Comment: You can read in the manual pages of awk how it's used. It's main function is to be able to split output into fields. Of course it has a different usage syntax than grep. But that's obvious after reading 1 minute into it. If you add into the description what you tried to accomplish in the first place someone might be able to help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't understand what does  `awk "ibmc-s3-e2e-test"` mean. It doesn't check which line match the pattern `"ibmc-s3-e2e-test"`, like grep does, instead, it evaluates the value of a variable called `ibmc-s3-e2e-test`. Of course, it is empty. The default action for an empty value or zero is nothing. Therefore you see nothing.

If you want to check the pattern, do `yourCmd|awk '/pattern/'`